# javascript:post data to same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#list li').click(function(){
        var ID= $(this).attr('id');
        $.post("index.php", ID, 
            function(){
                $("#category").html(ID);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

This code shows my selected list ID in html `<div id="category">`.

## Question

Is there any way to post that data directly to PHP code and echo it? I need data in php, because I want to use it in my query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'index.php',
  data: { id: ID }, // name of the post variable ($_POST['id'])
  success: function(data) {
     console.log('successfully posted data! response body: ' + data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use ajax:

```
$('#list li').click(function(){
var ID = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax(
   url:"index.php", //Page with data
   data:{id: ID},
   type: "POST", //You can use any method POST, GET, DELETE, PUT...
   success:function(result){
      $("#category").html(result);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't sending a key/value pair ... only a value.

You also have not added the argument for the response in the completion callback

Change

```
$.post("index.php", ID, function(){
     $("#category").html(ID);
});
```

To

```
$.post("index.php", {id: ID}, function(response){ //object used for key/value pairs
      $("#category").html(response.data);
},'json')
.fail(function(error){
      alert("Ooops ..something went wrong");
});
```

Then for simple php test

```
echo json_encode(array('data'=>'The ID sent was '. $_POST['id']));
```

Comment: Am getting error  Notice: Undefined index: id  

on this line at my code:
echo json_encode(array('data'=>'The ID sent was '. $_POST['id']));

Comment: Did you use object the same way I showed? In browser dev tools (F12) network can inspect exactly what was sent. Could also do a dump of `$_POST` and see what it looks like in response body of request in dev tools or log it to console in callback

Comment: Am getting error  alert("Ooops ..something went wrong");

I added if (isset($_POST['id'])) line before echo json_encode(array('data'=>'THE id sent was'.$_POST['id']));

and It looks like variable is not posted at all

Comment: what do you see in browser console when you dump $_POST?

Comment: The code works in mozzilla network preview mode,
but in the main window after i select my list row, am getting 
.fail(function(error) message and THE id sent was'.$_POST['id']) is not shown

Comment: So what is actually being sent? What is actually being returned? You can inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network.Do some research into ajax debugging